# Why was a Plimsoll symbol chosen to indicate standard state?

Tags: thermodynamics, notation, history-of-chemistry

Historically, the Plimsoll symbol (aka Plimsoll line) was created as hull mark that would serve as a ready indicator of whether a ship was overloaded and thus running too low in the water.  It was later adopted by chemists to indicate standard state (currently defined by IUPAC as 1 bar).

Why was the Plimsoll symbol chosen for this purpose?  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plimsoll),

> The plimsoll symbol (⦵ or <s>o</s>) ... is used as a superscript in the notation of thermodynamics to indicate an arbitrarily chosen non-zero reference point ("standard state").

The language used by Wikipedia suggests it was chosen because it looks like a zero with a line through it, thus communicating "not zero".  Applying this to enthalpy or free energy seems redundant and unnecessary, though, since by definition there is no true zero reference point for either (among state functions, this exists only for entropy).  It's like having a special symbol attached to $ΔU$ to indicate that $U$ is conserved, when, of course, $U$ is always conserved.

Indeed, the problem with attaching a symbol to $U$ saying it's conserved is that it suggests that sometimes $U$ is *not* conserved (otherwise why would you need the symbol?).  Likewise, attaching a symbol to $U$, $H$, or $G$ saying that the reference state is non-zero suggests sometimes it could be zero.  I.e., I understand they needed a symbol for reference state.  But I'm puzzled why they chose one that communicated "non-zero" instead of just choosing something that meant "reference", period.

Nevertheless, I'm sure these people knew what they were doing, and had good reasons for what they did.  I just don't understand what that those reasons would be.  I'd thus be interested to hear from anyone out there with knowledge of the history of this.

Perhaps the answer (here I speculate) is that they wanted to communicate the obvious (that thermodynamic reference states can never be true zero reference states) — and that the reason they wanted to do this was because they anticipated tables of thermodynamic values would be used by a broad audience, some of whom might not understand the underlying thermodynamic theory.

Comment: I've always thought of it as a naught. This is the first time I hear of a nautical association. My concern is usually with choosing the right symbol. The fact that there are two choices (⦵ or o) seems a potential source of confusion. I've encountered the "naught" symbol more frequently, either empty or filled (but meaning different things). I think the idea was to employ a small, tidy and distinct symbol, the likeness to "zero" indicating a "ground" and thus reference state. Presumably the answer is buried in a grave or a library on the history of science. Also, check with IUPAC, as usual.

Comment: Sure enought, reading in IUPAC's notation guidelines (Pure & Appl.Chem.., Vol.54, No.6, pp. 1239—1250, 1982.), starting in section 2.2 and continuing in section 4, you see that use of the naught symbol is more common than that of plimsoll. That extra little line is bound to have cost the plimsoll in popularity. In any case, it's a really interesting origin story, would be good to see a complete answer.

Comment: @TryHard Note that in the citation, there was missing strike (horizontal bar) in the second symbol. (Now fixed.)

Comment: Plimsoll symbol was commonly used in the literature in XIX century to show the *non-zero nature* of standard values. It's ironic that due to typographical reasons that plimsoll symbol is often replaced by a zero sign in the superscript (ligatures for upper `0`s were everywhere, but upper `⦵`s were not so ubiquitous).

Comment: I find the argument that there is no true zero energy unconvincing. For instance, as the universe expands and exhausts entropy, isn't it also heading to a lower energy state? As you extrapolate, won't we reach a state that you can define as "zero energy". Isn't it just a matter of historical accident, of choosing reference states that are not true zeros.

Comment: The reference in Wikipedia for the history of this notation is "Prigogine, I. & Defay, R. (1954) Chemical thermodynamics, p. xxiv". Does anyone have a copy of this text? Does it cite a primary source?

Comment: Also, is there a geographical preference for the Plimsoll? I've never seen it in my US texts, which use the open circle "$^\circ$".

Comment: @Andrew This is a pure speculation, but probably it was either a political decision at that time (why would U.S. press promote a British MP by using his symbol?) or the lack of typographic equipment (Germany is/has been known as the major supplier of all sorts of advanced typographic machinery and ligatures; probably U.S. companies decided not to buy overseas and use what they had).

Comment: Atkins (Oxford U.) seems to use the plimsoll exclusively in his textbook.

Comment: According to Chemical Thermodynamics: An Introduction, by Ernö Keszei, IUPAC introduced the plimsoll in 1970 to denote the reference state. Since IUPAC was established in 1919, it's relevant that they waited so long to comment on this point (although perhaps they changed their opinion over time). My guess is that the two ecosystems coexisted peacefully but growing globalization required IUPAC eventually to pass judgement. Being exposed to and comfortable with different notations through journals it is likely that chemists never considered this question particularly important.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prigogine's *Chemical Thermodynamics* gives a bit more context as to why a plimsoll symbol is somewhat more preferable and is indeed used to denote non-zero nature of standard values [1, pp. xxiv, 86]:

> The properties of a *pure substance* are denoted by a superscript $^0$. The use of this symbol to denote "standard" thermodynamic quantities is then permissible only when these refer to the pure substance as standard state. Some other convention is needed to denote the more general "standard quantities" defined in equation (7.51), where the standard state may for example refer to an infinitely dilute solution. After much consideration the symbol $^⦵$ has been introduced. This symbol is based on the circle, and is thus closely related to the more common (but occasionally confusing) notation for standard quantities. It seems useful, however, to associate it with the plimsoll mark which, appropriately enough, refers to a reference state of loading of a ship; this use of an ideogram has, we believe, some value in keeping the essential nature of "standard states" in prominence.
>
> Quantities denoted by the plimsoll symbol are still, in general, 
>   functions of temperature and pressure; the idea of "standardization" 
>   of temperature and pressure is not stressed. When necessary we denote 
>   quantities at the *standard pressure* (which for convenience is nearly 
>   always chosen as the unit of pressure) by the superscript $^†$, quantities at a *standard volume* (which for convenience is always chosen as the unit of volume) are denoted by $^‡$. Quantities referring to a (usually hypothetical) ideal system are denoted by $^\mathrm{id}$.
>
> [...]
>
> $$P = P^⦵(T,p) + P^M(T,p,x_1\ldots x_c) \tag{7.51}$$

It's also interesting that Lewis and Randall, known for defining the standard state in the beginning of XX century as we know it, used an upper circle [2, p.623]:

> $G^\circ$ A property of a substance in its standard state.

However, they referred to it as to a *standard **reference** state* (distinguished from a standard state) throughout the textbook [2, p. 88, 99]:

> While we cannot give the absolute magnitude of $\bar{H}$ for a substance in solution, we may ascertain how much greater or less this is than the heat content of the same substance in some chosen state. Thus, at any temperature, if we are dealing with the partial molal heat content of water in some solution in which water is the solvent, we may choose pure liquid water as the reference state, and denote its molal heat content by $H_1^\circ$.
>
> [...]
>
> It is highly convenient, especially for purposes of concise tabulation, to know the heats of reaction when various substances are formed from their elements. It is therefore desirable to choose some one *standard reference state* for each element. For this purpose, we shall, at all temperatures, take the element at a pressure of one atmosphere, and in that form which is most stable or most common at room temperature. Thus liquid mercury, gaseous oxygen, solid iodine, rhombic 
>   sulfur and graphitic carbon, all under a pressure of one atmos­phere, will be considered to be in their *standard reference state*.

#### References

1. Prigogine, I.; Defay, R. Chemical Thermodynamics; Treatise On Thermodynamics; *Longmans, Green & Co Ltd: Glasgow*, **1954**; Vol. 1.
2. Lewis, G. N.; Randall, M. Thermodynamics and the Free Energy of Chemical Substances, First Edition later Printing edition.; *McGraw-Hill Book Company*, **1923**.

Comment: What's the difference between a "standard state" and a "standard reference state"? Isn't use of the word "reference" redundant in that context? To quote eg Atkins: "the standard state of a substance at a specified temperature is its pure form at 1 bar pressure."

Comment: Does that mean that "reference" implies a different stated pressure?

Comment: @TryHard The term "standard reference state" arose from the need to use some starting point to quantitatively describe thermodynamic functions of state such as heat of formation. Regarding the pressure, well, Lewis used 1 atm instead of these days' 1 bar ( I added additional quote on that).

Comment: I was trying to see how you did a plimsoll in MathJax, but it turned out you just pasted one in... :)

Comment: @Zhe Yep, I did, MathJax is very friendly towards Unicode:) I think we already had similar discussion and I suggested to use a [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) –  an efficient way to insert any character without the need to remember arcane Unicode sequences or waste time searching the internet:)

Comment: Summarizing what Prigogine wrote, it seems the open circle meant "pure substance", and the horizontal bar was then added to indicate a "standard quantity" of that pure substance, rather than standard pressure (the latter instead being designated with a single dagger).  Hence there was no notion of "not-zero" when the bar was originally introduced, and the Plimsoll was chosen simply because they needed to add *something* to the zero and, hey, there's already this good-looking compact symbol that does that and, in another well-known application, already has the connotation of "reference value".

Comment: And if my summary is correct, it must then be the case that the horizontal symbol's meaning was subsequently (between when Prigogine wrote this in 1954 and IUPAC's formal action in 1970) migrated from "standard quantity" to "standard state".  And perhaps at that time the "not-zero" association was introduced?